# Synchronize file system with object hierarchy

Tags: algorithm, filesystems, synchronization

Are there any patterns or best practices for keeping a hierarchy of objects consistent with the file system?

Each object corresponds with a file on the file system. Files can be added, changed, deleted etc and the object hierarchy should be adapted accordingly.

Please don't answer along the lines of "discard files, use a database".

Comment: Do you need to observe changes that are made by processes outside your control?

Comment: in delphi I did something you interested in, sync the contents of directories with an xml structure. I would describe it in an answer, but it's more technical, and would be specific to delphi, than your question. But if you like, I can share the steps.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to check how the target OS lets you watch the filesystem. On Linux there's the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) API. On Windows you wait on the notification handle created by the [FindFirstChangeNotification()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call. Both let you avoid active polling of the directory for changes.